# composite function of several variables

Tags: functions, multivalued-functions

recalling functions of single variable ,when writting \begin{gather} (f\circ g) (x)=f(g(x)) \end{gather}

this means the $x$ in the domain of $g$ and $g(x)$ in the domain of $f$,that makes the independent variable to $f$ is $g(x)$ but the independant variable of $(f\circ g)$ is $x$ .

according to the above argument if \begin{gather} Z(x,h(x)) \end{gather}

this implies that $x$ and $h(x)$ is in domain of $Z $, then $Z$ still a function of several variables ?

Am I understand it correctly ?

Comment: In order to write down $Z(x, h(x))$, you need that $x$ belongs to the domain of $h$ and that the ordered pair $(x, h(x))$ belongs to the domain of the two-variable function $Z$.  The composite function $Z(x, h(x)) = Z \circ ( id, h)$ (where $id$ represents the identity function) is a function of a single variable.

Comment: but if $z$ is converted to single variable function ,how in all single variable calculus books when dealing with composite functions we take if $f(g(x))$ the $g(x)$ is it's domain and it's single variable and the proof of chain rule depend on that

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot decipher your comment for a combination of reasons, including the unclear grammatical structure and your failure to articulate your ideas in a clear way for someone who doesn't already know what you're talking about.  Please feel free to try again -- and please make an effort to communicate more carefully and clearly.

Comment: But also: the function $Z$ is not "converted" to anything.  The function $Z$ has domain some set of ordered pairs (perhaps $\mathbb{R}^2$), while the function $Z \circ (id, h)$ has perhaps the domain $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $id$ and $h$ are both functions of one variable, the function $(id, h)$ has domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the meaning of $Z$ when you pass from one to another, so it is technically a different function.

A simple example.  Suppose $Z(x,y)=5x-3y$ as a function $Z: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.  This is a function of two variables.  If we suddenly declare $y=h(x)= 3x$ then we have $Z(x,3x)=5x-9x=-4x$, which is a function of the single variable $x$.  However, this "new" $Z$ is actually a different function, as its domain is now $\mathbb{R}$.